# Trying to understand difference between loops/paths and functions

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm learning the very basics of algebraic topology right now and one thing has got me really confused.

For example, take $S^1$ the circle. Then we know that a loop around the circle once given by the function $f: I \to S^1$ $f(t) = e^{2\pi i t}$ is not homotopic to the loop around the circle twice given by the function $g: I \to S^1$ $f(t) = e^{4\pi i t}$. This is because the fundamental group of the circle is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. However it's clear that $g$ and $f$ are... equal as functions, as in they are pointwise equal. So what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As John said, they are not equal functions because, although they have the same range (in fact they are both surjective as functions), $f$ is a one-to-one function and $g$ is a two-to-one function.

As far as giving an intuitive explanation for why they are not homotopic, perhaps it's easier to add a dimension to see what's going on.

If you have a cylinder (which is homotopy equivalent to the circle), then when you wrap a rubber band around it once, and when you wrap a rubber band around it twice (I'm sure you've done this with a rubber band on pencils or your finger before), then it's pretty clear that you can't move the rubber band around on the surface of the cylinder so that it takes one rubber band to the other. You would have to take the rubber band off of the surface first which means there can't be a homotopy between the two.

Answer (score 0):

They're not pointwise equal. For instance, $f(1/2) = e^{\pi i} = -1$, while $g(1/2) = e^{2 \pi i} = 1$. Does that help?

Comment: Oh I see yeah. Thanks.

Comment: Is there some intuitive way to see that they're not homotopic?

Comment: Look at the winding number of the curve about the origin (I'm hoping you've heard of this from complex variables, and know it can be defined by an integral). In general a small deformation of the curve will change the winding number by a small amount (unless the deformation makes the curve pass through the origin, which can't happen for a curve in $S^1$). Since the winding number is an integer, this "small amount" must be zero. In other words, winding-number-around-origin is invariant under homotopy of loops in $S^1 \subset \mathbb C$. Your curves have winding numbers 1 and 2, respectively.